# iDRAC monitoring with zabbix

Tags: centos, snmp, zabbix, mib

I want to monitoring my Dell's iDRAC with Zabbix 3.0 (on Centos7). But it does not load the custom MIB. I tried every solutions what I found, but its still do nothing.

Zabbix error:

> SNMP agent item "sysUpTime" on host "host_name" failed: first
>   network error,

I tried to put "mibs +ALL" to snmpd.conf. (and etc)

I can run this command:

> snmpwalk -v2c -c Gate1 -O e xxx.xxx.xxx.xx

But its dont load the Dell's MIB.

**Edit:**

The zabbix cant connect to iDRAC over SNMP.

Error:
SNMP agent item "sysUpTime" on host "Gate1_iDRAC" failed: first network error, wait for 15 seconds

I selected "Templates SNMP Devices", but the other hosts are still working fine with SNMP.

**Edit2:**

Okay, i had to define in macros the {$SNMP_COMMUNITY}, and now, its working w/o DELL's MIB.

**The END**

The macro has solved the problem, so everything work fine. 
This is my fault.

(Reallly sorry for my English)

Comment: That is unlikely to be related to MIBs. Verify that the port and community are correctly specified. Note that the community can be specified for each item - you probably want to use usermacro for that.

Comment: The port and community are working fine. I can run query with defaults MIBs. (IP-MIB, TCP-MIB, SNMPv2-MIB, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Fill the  {$SNMP_COMMUNITY} macro at the host settings.

Comment: Slightly disappointed that you responded to my comment about the community possibly being the problem with "The port and community are working fine" and then configuring the community.

Comment: Im really sorry, I misunderstood. But thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**mib2zabbix**

Perl script will generate a Zabbix v3 Template in XML format from an OID tree in a SNMP MIB file.

Read more [here](https://github.com/cavaliercoder/mib2zabbix)